# log4net not working using log4net appender azure in MVC applcation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, log4net, azure-storage, log4net-appender

same `log4net appender azure nuget` code working fine for `console app,
but not working in MVC application`.

I'm using this nuget [`log4net.Appender.Azure 1.1.1`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net.Appender.Azure)

already added `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();`
 in Global.asax
`web.config`

```
  <log4net>
    <!-- Azure Table Appender, uncomment, set proper QueueName and AWS credentials (appSettings) to try it out -->
    <appender name="AzureAppender1" type="log4net.Appender.AzureTableAppender, log4net.Appender.Azure">
      <param name="TableName" value="test" />
      <param name="ConnectionString" value="***" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
```

> Can anyone know why it is not working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure - but I would be a little careful about using Tables for large scale logging scenarios. Take a look at the logging anti-pattern in this [Table Design Guide](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/#table-design-patterns). It can often lead to hot partitions - and often times the scenario is much better supported using Blobs.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go I found that it is problem od log4net dll version.
in nuget `log4net appender azure` version of `log4net` dll is `1.2.12` it is the older one. need should be updated to newer version `1.2.13`

that solves the above issue.

Comment: Simply run Update-Package log4net in package manager console.